# Run update or insert query after select query in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, insert-update

I have a large data feed each morning that is dumped into a SQL Server table with a truncate query.

I need to update parts of my master table with any changes from this dump
and append any new rows (basically the rest) to my Master table also from this dump.

To reduce the run time this truncate query is about to be modified to cover only the last 2 years.

How should I go about do this

Both tables have identical structure so hopefully this should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: What you are asking isn't really clear. You might need to provide more detail on the structure you're working with and how it is going to change. When you say "truncate query", do you mean that the source table is completely cleared and repopulated? If the data provided changes to a more limited set, and you're only either updating or inserting new records, why does anything in your process need to change? If something isn't included in the source because it's old, nothing will happen in your master table, right?

Comment: Simple way would be to add a column LastModifiedOn (Datetime) and based on any recent changes, you could insert or update the other table.

Comment: Hi cf_en 
When you say "truncate query", do you mean that the source table is completely cleared and repopulated? YES
I'm updating any record changes over the last 2 years and inserting any new records. any records in the daily data set that have not changed or already exist can be ignored

Comment: Hi SQL_M
I like this idea of LastModifiedOn (Datetime) not sure if this would work yet though, but my main issue is how best to write the insert-update query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apt way of doing should be a merge statement.
See here for more
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

The scenario mentioned in Example C would be the case you should follow.

```
-- Create a temporary table variable to hold the output actions.  
DECLARE @SummaryOfChanges TABLE(Change VARCHAR(20));  

MERGE INTO Sales.SalesReason AS Target  
USING (VALUES ('Recommendation','Other'), ('Review', 'Marketing'), 
              ('Internet', 'Promotion'))  
       AS Source (NewName, NewReasonType)  
ON Target.Name = Source.NewName  
WHEN MATCHED THEN  
UPDATE SET ReasonType = Source.NewReasonType  
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
INSERT (Name, ReasonType) VALUES (NewName, NewReasonType)  
OUTPUT $action INTO @SummaryOfChanges;  

-- Query the results of the table variable.  
SELECT Change, COUNT(*) AS CountPerChange  
FROM @SummaryOfChanges  
GROUP BY Change;
```

Comment: Hi Samuel A C
That appears to be the guidence I was looking for so thank you very much.
My initial run will take 2 hours to complete but then after that my new master file should run much quicker as the dataset will be smaller and the UPDATE/INSERTS will be much less.